# Nginx server with node returns js code

Tags: node.js, nginx

I learning node. I taked ubuntu server, installed nodejs and trying to set nginx by using some guides. All looks fine but... server returned me my app.js code instead of the index page. What i did wrong? Thanks!

`hack-it-up.ru.conf :`

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    server_name hack-it-up.ru www.hack-it-up.ru;

    include /etc/nginx/snippets/letsencrypt.conf;

    location / {
        return 301 https://www.hack-it-up.ru$request_uri;
    }

}


server {
    server_name www.hack-it-up.ru;
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server ipv6only=on;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.hack-it-up.ru/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.hack-it-up.ru/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.hack-it-up.ru/fullchain.pem;
    include /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl.conf;

    root /var/www/hack-it-up.ru;
    index app.js;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}


server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name hack-it-up.ru;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.hack-it-up.ru/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.hack-it-up.ru/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.hack-it-up.ru/fullchain.pem;
    include /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl.conf;

    location / {
        return 301 https://www.hack-it-up.ru$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Comment: NGINX will not execute your code, you have to set it up so it passes ("proxies") requests to your Node.js app. See [this](http://www.nikola-breznjak.com/blog/javascript/nodejs/using-nginx-as-a-reverse-proxy-in-front-of-your-node-js-application/) or [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-14-04#set-up-reverse-proxy-server).

Comment: You should listen to a certain port number in your node application and forward your requests to this port from nginx

Answer (score 0):

I got this error cuz i maked wrong index file. It must be `index /bin/www`